# Style for a CustomControl is not applied in Generic file

Tags: styles, uwp, custom-controls, uwp-xaml

I have a custom control, in that custom control I have loaded the `TextBox`, and I have customized the style for `TextBox` in Generic.XAML file but the style is not applied, Please refer the below code

**CustomControl.cs**

```
class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1);
    }
}
```

**Generic.XAML**

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CustomControl">
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBox Width="100" Height="100" Text="Hi"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**MainWindow.XAML**

```
<Page
x:Class="CustomControl.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CustomControl"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <local:CustomControl1   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="200"/>
</Grid>
```

I have set the foreground color for TextBox in Generic.XAML file but that is not set to the TextBox. Please refer the below image,

[image]

If I customized the style for a TextBox in Page.Resources in MainWindow.XAML its works fine. But I need to customized in Generic.XAML itself.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions:

1. Just set the `Foreground` property on the `TextBox`.

Since you ask this question, I suppose you'll have multiple `TextBox`es and don't want to repeat setting the property. If the color has to change some day, you'll have a lot of work.

2. Give your `TextBox` style a key and apply that style.

Easy fix, but not perfect if have multiple types of controls with `Foreground` property.

```
<Style x:Key="RedStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl1" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBox Width="100" Height="100" Text="Hi" Style="{StaticResource RedStyle}"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

3. Define the `Foreground` property on your template and use `TemplateBinding`

This is my favorite fix.

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl1" >
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBox Width="100" Height="100" Text="Hi" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```